# why doesn't it execute the function inside the onsubmit?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <form action="#" onsubmit="ejecucion()" class="was-validated">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="sleep">Tiempo entre mediciones:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sleep" placeholder="Tiempo en minutos entre mediciones (por defecto es 2 minutos)" name="sleep" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">OK!</div>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Ingrese un valor! Unicamente numeros!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="points">Cantidad de puntos en grafico/s:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="points" placeholder="Ingrese la cantidad de puntos que desea ver en los graficos (por defecto es 300 puntos)" name="points" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Ingrese un valor! Unicamente numeros!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" required> Verifique los valores introducidos
        <div class="valid-feedback">OK!</div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Configurar</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
const config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);


function ejecucion(){
    var sleep  = document.getElementById("sleep").value;
    var points = document.getElementById("points").value;

    firebase.database().ref('dispositivos/' + mac + "/config/control").set({
        delay: sleep,
        points: points
      });

    location.replace("home.html"); // Redirecciono al inicio
}
```

If i put a cosole.log it runs when the form is submitted but neither the firebase write nor the redirect works.

**I do not put the configuration of the database since it does not belong to me, anyway in my test code it is configured correctly since I make readings of the database successfully. 
I don't get errors on the console when executing the code.**

Comment: `mac` is missing?

Comment: no, the mac is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing to the Firebase Realtime Database happens asynchronously. Currently you navigate away from the page before the write operation is sent to the database. To wait until the write is complete, use a `then()` block:

```
firebase.database().ref('dispositivos/' + mac + "/config/control").set({
  delay: sleep,
  points: points
}).then(function() {
  location.replace("home.html"); // Redirecciono al inicio
})
```

Comment: I am trying to apply that concept in the following code, without succes, sometimes it works and sometimes no,could you please help me?  `ref2.once('value').then(function(snapshot){
    console.log("Entre en el ref");
    if(snapshot.val() != null){
      console.log("existe");
      if(pass == "4920" ){
        ref.update({ //Link mac to user
          [p]: cant,
          [cant]: mac
      }).then(function(){
          console.log("Link done!");
      });
      }
      else{
        console.log("Wrong password!");
      }
    }
    else
      console.log("no existe");
  });`

Comment: That sounds like a new problem, so should be a new question. In there be sure to also post what doesn't work about it, as that is unclear from seeing the code.